# I want to know file creation date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a files list which contain the directory of file. I want to know file creation date of that files. I used fileInof.CreationTime. But It is not displayed creation date. How I can know about this.

```
'Get file info
Dim FileInfoVar As FileInfo = New FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/A.png"))

Dim DateVar as datetime = FileInfoVar.CreationTime
```

It didn't display real creation time. It displays like this 1/1/1611.

Answer (score 1):

File.GetCreationTime gives you a DateTime object...which is of course a Date and a Time. Reading out the properties of the resulting object should give exactly what you need.

**Edit:**
Looking at your editted question I seriously doubt that you are looking at the right file. Did you do a File.Exists first? The result you have now seems a bit weird.

Comment: The file have existed this path. And File.Exists was been true.

Comment: It's really weird. Is this your only code? If not, try to start a new test project and just code this piece and see what happens.